# Magento coupon $10 off per item in cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to setup a Coupon Code in Magento to allow $10 (or any specific amount) off per item in the cart.

So if I have 1 item in cart I get $10 off, if I have 2 items in cart I get $20 off, etc... Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Fixed amount discount` as an action to apply.

Check http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_5 for more information